# Hiding items in org-agenda view and calendar

Tags: org-agenda, calendar

When I still used Emacs Diary as my default organizer I valued its ability to mark items on the calendar. One could also make an entry that was NOT so marked by placing an ampersand before the entry. The entry would appear in the diary but would not be marked in the calendar. I have since switched to org-agenda and have set up calendar (and also calw-org) to display my org-agenda files. However, there are certain appointments I would like to hide from being marked in the calendar. How does one do this with an org-file?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by hiding from being marked? Do you not want certain appointments showing up in the agenda?

Comment: I would like both to prevent some items from showing up in the Calendar and also in the Agenda. If I use Emacs Diary to create an appointment, it will look like this generally:

Apr 11, 2019 Visit uncle Bob

However if I add & to the beginning as in:

&Apr 11, 2019 Visit uncle Bob

Then the appointment is *not* marked in the calendar. I.e. if I open calendar, that appointment does not count to marking the day as busy. This is useful for finding free time slots in the coming week or month(s).

Comment: The following link explains the mark in the Emacs Manual:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Displaying-the-Diary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a part answer to my question above. To hide tasks from Agenda-View one needs only capture the tasks using an inactive time stamp rather than an active one. I have not yet found a way to prevent items from being marked in calendar.